# Possible to Import wallet from keystore folder?

Tags: go-ethereum, import, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have ethereum setup on my ubuntu machine. And i do have the Keystore folder on cold storage. How do I import these wallets?

Comment: Sorry i meant "import accounts from the keystore folder"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the "Keystore" folder into the .ethereum (Hidden folder in Ubuntu) then run geth -updatedb to syncronize

Comment: This answer has been flagged by the community as a low quality score and possible duplicate. Please click on the "Edit" text below your answer to edit your answer.